# How do I make a custom login form for Omniauth with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I am using Omniauth as my only authentication, there is no `:database_authentication` on my model. I want to login through Atlassian Crowd using this gem: https://github.com/robdimarco/omniauth_crowd

That gem uses the standard Crowd login form, which I don't want. I want to make a custom form that acts the same way, but takes place of the login page entirely (no "Sign in with Crowd") or anything like that, just a form that logs into Crowd.

To do this, I've added this option to my `config.omniauth` line in devise.rb:

```
:form => Devise::SessionsController.actions(:new)
```

Which, from what I can see online, will use that Rack endpoint to display a custom form. I've changed the html in app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb to new.html.haml, which contains this form:

```
= simple_form_for @user, :url => user_omniauth_authorize_path(:crowd) do |f|
  = f.input :username, :input_html => { :name => 'username' }
  = f.input :password, :input_html => { :name => 'password' }
  = f.button :submit
```

Which I am hoping with mimic the default OmniAuth form. The problem is that when I visit users/auth/crowd with the `:form` options in my devise.rb, I get the error:

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/auth/crowd".
```

Is there a way to provide a custom form for OmniAuth like this, when using Devise?

edit: Here are the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth' } do
  get 'login', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  get 'logout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end

devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/auth/:provider', :to => 'users/omniauth#passthru'
  match '/users/auth/failure', :to => 'users/omniauth#failure'
end

resources :users
```

I've tried several things here, but nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: How are your routes defined?

Comment: What name did you give your omniauth controller? `Users::OmniauthController`? Is it inside a folder called `users`? What are the actions defined in that controller?

Comment: Yes. Yes. `crowd`, `failure`, `passthru`. The authentication works without the custom form if that helps.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are overriding the routes generated by devise, specifically the `passthru` route. You're making it accessible only through GET and as you may know a form defaults to POST. Remove that `devise_scope` block and try again.

Comment: Devise specifically says to use GET. But I don't think I need passthru anyway, because of route globbing. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview I've removed it. When I use a different controller for the form (like SessionsController instead of Devise::SessionsController), the form loads. But then I don't know what URL to POST to (I am getting a "No Credentials" error).

Comment: Oh, I now got what you are trying to accomplish. And I would advise against it. An integral part of delegated authentication is the trust conferred by the authenticating site not being a part of the authentication process. By using your own form, you are undermining that trust, people cannot be certain that they are submitting their username and password to the Crowd service.

Comment: I've got an additional `path_names` definition in a scenario like yours: `devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}, controllers: ...`. Doesn't seem 100% related though.

Comment: @Ashitaka - strangely, it seems like this is how Crowd is designed. https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Crowd+REST+Resources -- it specifically provides for checking to see if a given password is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be late, but I needed to do the same thing and maybe this will help someone else in the future. In my case, I was developing an internal application that needed to use the same accounts as the ones on our own crowd server. No sort of security concerns as far as I'm aware of since we are only talking to our own internal crowd server. I wanted to style the login page to match the aesthetics of the application.

When adding the omniauth_crowd gem and after configuring it with Devise, you should have a route that looks like this:

```
user_omniauth_authorize    GET|POST    /users/auth/:provider(.:format)    authentication#passthru {:provider=>/crowd/}
```

All I had to do was create a custom devise session form that mimics how the default omniauth_crowd one works. Basically it just POSTs a username and password param to your server. Creating custom devise views is described at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag user_omniauth_authorize_path(:crowd) do %>
  <div><%= label_tag :username, "Username" %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :username %></div>

  <div><%= label_tag :password, "Password" %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :password %></div>

  <div><%= submit_tag "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been trying to do exactly this with Crowd as well.

Answer (score 0):

I perfectly understand what you are trying to do. But there are many reasons because of which I would advise you to refrain from doing it. As

1. The basic concept of omniauth is that people can trust that they are logging in from a website they are familiar with.
2. If you remove that page and add your own page then the user may believe that you have some malicious reasons to do the same.

## I don't have enough repo to comment that is why I wrote this as an answer